# Unity cannot find script of other GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem getting a variable from script from another GameObject.. I have used this type of referring before and I know how it works, but for some reason it's saying it can't find the script I am referring to.

The code that is referring to the other code (if statements at the start of CanHearPlayer()):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemySight : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject Player;
public float fieldOfViewDegrees = 30;
public float visibilityDistance = 50;
public bool SeeingPlayer;
public float deathDistance;
public float hearDistance;

void Update(){
    SeeingPlayer = CanSeePlayer();
    float Distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player.transform.position);

    if ((SeeingPlayer == true)) {
        transform.LookAt(Player.transform.position);

        if (Distance < deathDistance){
            Debug.Log("You died");
            //Game over sequence starts here
        }
    }

    if (CanHearPlayer () == true) {
        Debug.Log ("I can hear you.");
    }
}

protected bool CanSeePlayer()
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    Vector3 rayDirection = Player.transform.position - transform.position;

    if ((Vector3.Angle(rayDirection, transform.forward)) <= fieldOfViewDegrees * 0.5f)
    {
        // Detect if player is within the field of view
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, rayDirection, out hit, visibilityDistance))
        {
            return (hit.transform.CompareTag("Player"));
        }
    }

    return false;
}

protected bool CanHearPlayer(){

    RaycastHit hit;
    Vector3 rayDirection = Player.transform.position - transform.position;

    if (Player.GetComponent<FirstPersonController>().MakingWalkingSound == true) {
        hearDistance = 50;
    } else {
        hearDistance =  5;
    }

    if (Player.GetComponent<FirstPersonController>().MakingRunningSound == true) {
        hearDistance = 100;
    }

    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, rayDirection, out hit, hearDistance))
    {
        return (hit.transform.CompareTag("Player"));
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

The public GameObject 'Player' is defined in Unity as the object which contains the 'FirstPersonController' script as a component.

Code it is referring to (part of it):

```
public class FirstPersonController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool MakingWalkingSound;
    public bool MakingRunningSound;

private void GetInput(out float speed)
{
     // Read input
    float horizontal = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float vertical = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Vertical");
    MakingWalkingSound = !(horizontal == 0 && vertical == 0);

    MakingRunningSound = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift);
}
```

The errors read: Assets/EnemySight.cs(53,41): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'FirstPersonController' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
And: Assets/EnemySight.cs(59,41): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'FirstPersonController' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

These lines correspond to the first two if-statements in CanHearPlayer.

What am I doing wrong? I've searched on Google and StackOverflow, but I cannot find what the problem is..

Thanks!

Comment: It's odd that it reports the error on lines 53 and 59, when there are not that many lines in EnemySight.cs. Are you sure you pasted at the correct file? Is FirstPersonController in it's own file - it should be.

Comment: Thank you for your response! EnemySight is shortened a little as well, I did not mention that. But like I said, the errors refer to the if-statements in CanHearPlayer.

Comment: When you say shortened, did you omit a namespace directive in either file?

Comment: Not that I know of.. I will include the full code in the first post

Comment: In FirstPersonController.cs, any namespace in there? and is it in /Assets folder also ?

Comment: Ah, yes, there is indeed a namespace in the FirstPersonController. I think I will be able to solve it, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there is some namespace declaration on your FirstPersonController class you need to declare using on your EnemySight code. Just like:

```
namespace MyNamespace.Blah { 
    public class FirstPersonController : MonoBehaviour {
        ...
    }
}
```

and...

```
using MyNamespace.Blah;

public class EnemySight : MonoBehaviour {
    ...
}
```

for monodevelop you can use alt+spacebar when declaring classes that are not already in your using scope and it will place using on top of the class for you.